# WP7 - Deserializing a XML file in isolated storage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xml-deserialization

I am creating a application in Windows Phone 7 Mango, and when I load up the application, the MainViewModel loads all the info from a file in isolated storage, with this function:

```
 private ObservableCollection<KasutajadViewModel> LoadUsers()
    {
        ObservableCollection<KasutajadViewModel> kasutajad = new ObservableCollection<KasutajadViewModel>();
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Kasutajad.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<PiletViewModel>));
                    //ObservableCollection<KasutajadViewModel> data
                    kasutajad =
                        (ObservableCollection<KasutajadViewModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return kasutajad;
    }
```

Problem is, that the deserializer doesn't return the data. 
Even when the XML file it reads from is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfKasutajadViewModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <KasutajadViewModel>
    <Nimi>Reigo Hein</Nimi>
    <Isikukood>96952422597</Isikukood>
 </KasutajadViewModel>
</ArrayOfKasutajadViewModel>
```

That is produced by a SaveUsers function, but I think this is redundant for the problem. 
The LoadUsers loads the stream correctly, but the deserialization doesn't output the required data.

Hope anyone can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a XmlSerializer for an ObservableCollection of `PiletViewModel`, yet you're deserializing an array of `KasutajadViewModel`. There's a type inconsistency here.